# SSRS: How to add an expression to a property that only accepts strings?

Tags: string, reporting-services, properties, expression, ssrs-2012

I have added a line object to an SSRS report and I want to specify its location property using an expression. But the Location property only accepts strings.
[Image of property window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Siy.png)
Formatting in SSRS can be annoying when trying to deal with margins. Thus, I want to put a vertical line on the report to indicate where my tables should stop. To know where to put the line I need to take into account the size of margins I am using. I created a report variable called "marginSize" and would like to use it in an expression to calculate the location for the line.

Expression = (11 - 2*Variables!marginSize.Value)

Note: 11 is width of the page with landscape layout.

Comment: unfortunately, the location property will not accept an expression

Comment: I am perplexed why you are using a line to indicate where your tables start.  Why not simply set the margins in the report itself and place the tables (or whatever) right up to the edge?  I'm sure there could be a good reason, I just can't see it, could you help me understand the why?  Thanks, and welcome.